# Pandas dataframe `apply` using recursive lambda function possible?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, recursion, apply

I have a data frame that represents a recursive parent child relationship. The data in this case is called "factor families"

Each factor family contains a number of factors, which are weighted, adding up to 100% per family.

A factor may itself be a factor family

There is no limit to the depth of recursion

e.g.

```
    a               b               c
    10%             40%             50%
    |               |
---------       ---------
|   |   |       |   |   |
d   e   f       g   h   i
20% 30% 50%     10% 20% 70%
                    |
                ---------
                |       |
                k       l
                60%     40%
```

I have represented this with the following dataframe in pandas

```
python
df = pd.DataFrame({
"code": ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k"],
"weight": [0.1, 0.4, 0.5, 0.2, 0.3, 0.5, 0.1, 0.2, 0.7, 0.6, 0.4],
"parent_code":["", "", "", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "h", "h"]
})
df.set_index("code", inplace=True)
df
```

Output:

```
|code|weight|parent_code|
|----|------|-----------| 
|a   |0.1   |           |
|b   |0.4   |           |
|c   |0.5   |           |
|d   |0.2   |a          |
|e   |0.3   |a          |
|f   |0.5   |a          |
|g   |0.1   |b          |
|h   |0.2   |b          |
|i   |0.7   |b          |
|j   |0.6   |h          |
|k   |0.4   |h          |
|----|------|-----------|
```

I have then added a calculated column which is the weight of a factor multiplied up by its parent weights. I call this `terminal_weight`

The sum of terminal weights **of terminal nodes** (in this example c, d,e,f, g, k, l, i) is therefore 100%

```
python

def parent_weight(code, family_factors):
    if code in family_factors.index:
        return family_factors["weight"][code] * parent_weight(family_factors["parent_code"][code], family_factors)
    else:
        return 1



df["terminal_weight"] = df.apply(lambda x: parent_weight(x.name, df), axis=1)

df
```

output

```
|code|weight|parent_code|terminal_weight|
|----|------|-----------| --------------|
|a   |0.1   |           |0.100          |
|b   |0.4   |           |0.400          |
|c   |0.5   |           |0.500          |
|d   |0.2   |a          |0.020          |
|e   |0.3   |a          |0.030          |
|f   |0.5   |a          |0.050          |
|g   |0.1   |b          |0.040          |
|h   |0.2   |b          |0.080          |
|i   |0.7   |b          |0.280          |
|j   |0.6   |h          |0.048          |
|k   |0.4   |h          |0.032          |
|----|------|-----------| --------------|
```

So my question: Is there a smarter way to do this so that I dont have to define the `parent_weight` function? Can i somehow put this in a lambda function passed to `DataFrame.apply()`??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it this way, looping over subsets of the dataframe and using temporary columns to store the chained weights and current parent tested. Note that I replaced your blank strings in df by np.nan values.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
"code": ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k"],
"weight": [0.1, 0.4, 0.5, 0.2, 0.3, 0.5, 0.1, 0.2, 0.7, 0.6, 0.4],
"parent_code":[np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "h", "h"]
})


df['temp'] = df['parent_code']
df['terminal_weight'] = df['weight']


while True:
    
    parents = df[df.temp.notnull()][['temp']].drop_duplicates(keep='first').copy()
    if len(parents)==0:
        break
    
    parents = df[['code', 'terminal_weight', 'parent_code']].merge(
            parents.rename({"temp":"code"}, axis=1),
            on="code",
            how="inner"
            )
    parents.rename(
            {'terminal_weight':'weight_parent', 'code':'parent_code_temp', 'parent_code':'temp'}, 
            axis=1, 
            inplace=True
            )
    df = df.rename({'temp':'parent_code_temp'}, axis=1).merge(
            parents, 
            on='parent_code_temp', 
            how='left'
            )
    df.drop('parent_code_temp', axis=1, inplace=True)
    df["weight_parent"]= df["weight_parent"].fillna(1)
    df['terminal_weight'] = df['terminal_weight'] * df["weight_parent"]
    df.drop(['weight_parent'], axis=1, inplace=True)

    
df.drop('temp', axis=1, inplace=True)
print(df)
```